# Computing a tedious analytical limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to compute the following limit which I believe to exist for each $\alpha,\beta>0$. However, sometimes Mathematica is giving `ComplexInfinity`, sometimes no result at all. If I fix $\alpha,\beta>0$ it gives the correct result. Anyone knows a trick here in order to make Mathematica computing the limit?

```
g[x_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] =(1 - x)^-\[Beta] x^-\[Alpha] (-((
    x^\[Alpha] HypergeometricPFQ[{\[Alpha], \[Alpha], 
       1 - \[Beta]}, {1 + \[Alpha], 1 + \[Alpha]}, x])/\[Alpha]^2) + 
   Beta[x, \[Alpha], \[Beta]] (Log[x] - PolyGamma[0, \[Alpha]] + 
      PolyGamma[0, \[Alpha] + \[Beta]]));

Limit[g[x, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], x -> 1, Direction -> "FromBelow", 
 Assumptions -> 0 < \[Alpha] && 0 < \[Beta]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making use of `Series` instead of `Limit` works to me in 13.2 on Windows 10:

```
g[x_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] =(1 - x)^-\[Beta] x^-\[Alpha] (-((x^\[Alpha] 
HypergeometricPFQ[{\[Alpha], \[Alpha], 1 - \[Beta]}, {1 + \[Alpha], 1 + \[Alpha]}, x])/
\[Alpha]^2) +   Beta[x, \[Alpha], \[Beta]] (Log[x] - PolyGamma[0, \[Alpha]] +  PolyGamma[0, \[Alpha] + \[Beta]]));
(Series[g[x, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], {x, 1, 1}, 
Assumptions -> 0 < \[Alpha] && 0 < \[Beta] && x < 1] // Normal) /. x -> 1
```

> `(\[Pi] Csc[\[Pi] \[Beta]] (PolyGamma[0, \[Alpha]] -  PolyGamma[0, \[Alpha] + \[Beta]]))/( Gamma[1 - \[Beta]] Gamma[1 + \[Beta]]) +  0^-\[Beta] (((\[Alpha] + \[Beta]) Gamma[1 + \[Alpha]]^2 Gamma[ 1 + \[Beta]] (PolyGamma[0, \[Alpha]] -  PolyGamma[ 0, \[Alpha] + \[Beta]]))/(\[Alpha]^2 \[Beta] \ Gamma[\[Alpha]] Gamma[ 1 + \[Alpha] + \[Beta]]) + (\[Pi] Csc[\[Pi] \[Beta]] Gamma[ 1 + \[Alpha]] (-PolyGamma[0, \[Alpha]] +  PolyGamma[0, \[Alpha] + \[Beta]]))/(\[Alpha] Gamma[ 1 - \[Beta]] Gamma[\[Alpha] + \[Beta]]))`